# Using two dependent v-select boxes two ensure no duplication

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have two v-select boxes that share similar data. I pull some attachments from an email and load into an array. The issue is the one select box should only choose one document and the other select box should only allow items that are not selected in the first v-select box. My template code is as follows:

```
                            <v-select v-model="selectedResponses"
                                  :items="attachments"
                                  item-value="id"
                                  item-text="name"
                                  label="First Document"
                                  persistent-hint
                                  filled
                                  chips
                                  return-object></v-select>            
                        <v-select v-model="selectedSupportingDocs"
                                  :items="availableSupportingDocs"
                                  item-value="id"
                                  item-text="name"
                                  label="Additional Documents"
                                  persistent-hint
                                  multiple
                                  filled
                                  chips
                                  return-object></v-select>
```

I figured my best bet is to make the second v-select items a computed property based on removing the chosen value in the first v-select. The issue is whatever you select in the first box seems to be the only available option in the second v-select. Its almost like splice() is not working correctly.

```
            computed: {
            availableSupportingDocs() {
                if (this.selectedResponses == null) return this.attachments;

                for (let i = 0; i < this.attachments.length; i++) {
                    if (this.selectedResponses.id === this.attachments[i]["id"]) {
                        console.log(this.attachments[i]["name"])
                        console.log(this.attachments.slice().splice(i, 1))
                        return this.attachments.slice().splice(i,1)
                    }
                }

                return this.attachments
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, `.splice()` will modify the input array and return a new array containing the removed values:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4]
const splicedOff = arr.splice(2,1)

const s = JSON.stringify
console.log('spliced:', s(splicedOff), 'remaining:', s(arr))
```

So you return just the one element you did not want to return.

Some fixes I can think of:

- put the new array in a variable before using `.splice()` and return that

```
const newAttachments = this.attachments.slice()
newAttachments.splice(i,1)
return newAttachments
```

- use `.filter()`

```
return this.attachments.filter((_,ix) => i !== ix)
```

With `filter()` you can get rid of the outer loop too:

```
availableSupportingDocs() {
  return !this.selectedResponses 
  ? this.attachments
  : this.attachments.filter((attachment) => this.selectedResponses.id !== attachment.id)
}
```

---

As you wrote in the comments, when the `selectedResponses` change, you might have to update the value of `selectedSupportingDocs`. You can do this either with a watcher or an event handler.

A watch would look like this:

```
watch: {
  selectedResponses: function () {
    if(this.selectedResponses?.id === this.selectedSupportingDocs.id) {
      this.selectedSupportingDocs = null
    }
  },
},
```

In an event handler, you would add a `@change` to the `v-select`:

```html
<v-select
  v-model="selectedResponses"
  :items="attachments"
  ...
  @change="adjustSupportingDocsSelection"
/>
```

The handler then sits in the component methods:

```
methods: {
  adjustSupportingDocsSelection(){
    // content is same as above
  }
}
```

Personally, I'd probably go with the event handler, because it is more explicit. The watcher is great if there is another mechanism to change `selectedResponses` and it covers both. Chose what makes most sense to you.

Comment: The first approach you put works. The second approach seems to do the same as my original issue. I like the second approach because it looks clean and short and I think filter is a nice solution but not sure why its not working. Maybe it should be !==?

Comment: Yes, of course, it has to be `!==`. Sorry!

Comment: No need to be sorry as your answer is extremely helpful. My only other concern is when using the computed property and say the first selection box changes so it is removed from the seconds item array however if it was already selected in box 2 wouldnt it still exist in the v-model? Is there a way to clear out the v-model for any items that are no longer in the items prop? I tested it and it doesnt do it by default.

Comment: You can just unset the `selectedSupportingDocs`, I have added two ways you could do it to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I learned a lot through this answer that I can apply to other stuff in my application.

Comment: Just toying with your response for updating the v-model I used your filter approach from part 1 and its working flawelessly as a watcher : this.selectedSupportingDocs = this.selectedSupportingDocs?.filter((docs) => this.selectedResponses?.id !== docs.id) . I was just curious though couldnt this just be used in the compute property along with the other filter?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course, you can replace the computed `availableSupportingDocs` with an assignment in the watcher on `selectedResponses`  (or an event handler on the select). I'd say that it emphasizes the event structure, at the price of being less modular, but this is a purely aesthetic choice. I am not aware of any rules favoring one over the other (though you should not put the watcher into the computed, which would work too, but as a side-effect), and as far as I know, there is no considerable difference internally, so if you prefer it this way, it's great that you tried it out!